# Flutter: List of Function using inside '...List' causing 'Avoid using unnecessary statements' and does not work

Tags: flutter

```
class FunctionList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List _functionList = [
      '1',
      '2',
    ];

    List _color = [
       Colors.white,
       Colors.blue,
    ]

    List<Function> _tapFunction = [
      () {
        print('Function 1');
      },
      () {
        print('Function 2');
      },
    ];

    return Row(
      children: [
        ...List.generate(_functionList.length, (i) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('tappping');
              _tapFunction[i];
            },
            child: Container(
              color: _color[i]
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          );
        })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to use `...List.generate()`. However, I am getting

`Avoid using unnecessary statements.dart(unnecessary_statements) List<Function> _tapFunction`

and when I tap the `Container()`,

```
flutter: tappping
flutter: tappping
flutter: tappping
flutter: tappping
```

`_tapFunction[i]` does not work. I tried with `_tapFunction[i] as Function`, it removes the `Avoid using unnecessary statement` error, however, it does not work.

Comment: It is unnscessary statement - you are creating a list, just to unpack it with '...' and wrap it again in the list. you can use it directly: children: List.generate(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
   onTap: () {
              print('tappping');
              _tapFunction[i];
            },
```

to this:

```
   onTap: () {
              print('tappping');
              _tapFunction[i]();
            },
```